# ctags cannot find the definition of a local variable in a c function

Tags: ctags

I use `ctags -R *` to generate tag files. I have tried exuberant-ctags and universal-ctags.
In a c function, I define a local variable, but ctags cannot find the definition of the local variable. Is there any options for ctags to generate tags for local variables?

Comment: Google "ctags local". First result has the answer.

Comment: (Also, try `gd` on that local variable)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using universal-ctags, pass --kinds-C=+l.

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.c
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int r = 0;
    retunr 0;
}
$ u-ctags -o - --kinds-C=+l /tmp/foo.c
main    /tmp/foo.c  /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"   f   typeref:typename:int
r   /tmp/foo.c  /^  int r = 0;$/;"  l   function:main   typeref:typename:int    file:
$ u-ctags -o - --kinds-C=+lz /tmp/foo.c
argc    /tmp/foo.c  /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"   z   function:main   typeref:typename:int    file:
argv    /tmp/foo.c  /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"   z   function:main   typeref:typename:char **    file:
main    /tmp/foo.c  /^main(int argc, char **argv)$/;"   f   typeref:typename:int
r   /tmp/foo.c  /^  int r = 0;$/;"  l   function:main   typeref:typename:int    file:
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!